# HTML Listbox width when length is zero

Tags: html, listbox

I am trying to fill options into a listbox dynamically. I want to set a fixed width even there is no elements in it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Pekka, thanks for your response. I set listbox property as STYLE="width:85;" but its not working.

Comment: Where there are no elements in it, the markup is invalid. A `select` element's content model is "One or more option/optgroup elements".

Comment: @Kishor Kumar — 85 what? Miles? Use a validator.

Comment: @Quentin that sounds like a worthy answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CSS` to do this, since there's no html attribute that changes auto width of this object:

```
<select style="width: 300px">
```

Simple example.